# Is it possible to load different layout for single ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, illegalargumentexception

I have a 3 buttons for my app. LIBRARY, STORE & LATEST . When I click on any of these buttons, I want to load a different layout.For Library , aViewPager. For STORE, a ViewPager & for LATEST, a normal layout file. How to do that?

If I load ViewPager for Library & Store. When I rotate my device, then my app is getting crashed with `IllegalArgumentException : No view found for Id for Fragment.`

I tried many ways. I have also posted many questions. Still, no positive response.

Can anyone tell me on how to do that?

Comment: post what you have tried

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12902107/1410561
This is what I have tried.